# How are $y=x^3$ and $y=x^3-3x^2+3x+1 $ related?

Tags: conic-sections

I am working through a chapter on circles, tangents and parabolas and changes in origin. I am answering the questions at the end of a section on changes in origin. This question says sketch the following pairs of related curves:

$(a) y= x^3, y= x^3 - 3x^2+3x+1$

$(b) xy=1, xy=2x+y-1$

$(c) y^2=-12x, y^2= 12(y-x)$

This puzzles me. The preceding end of section questions have involved equations of parabolas in the form of $(y-k)^2=4a(x-h)$

These equations don't fit into that pattern. I can see that they all involve transitions and I could laboriously plot $y= x^3 - 3x^2+3x+1$ - or just plug it into Desmos - but I am thinking I must be missing the point.

So my question is: Are these questions simply asking me to plot the curves or is there some deeper significance which I am missing?

Comment: $x^3-3x^2+3x+1=(x-1)^3+2$

Comment: Ah, so I am looking to refactor these equations so that the shifts in x and y become apparent?

Comment: I think the question asks you to: (1) sketch the first curve of each pair, and then (2) use certain transforms to "convert" the sketch of the first curve into a sketch of the second curve, without doing much extra work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part a) has already been done. For part b), use [Simon's Favourite Factoring Trick](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Simon%27s_Favorite_Factoring_Trick) to get $xy - 2x - y + 1 = 0 \Rightarrow (x - 1)(y - 2) + \ ? = \ ?$

For part c), complete the square for $y^2 - 12y = -12x$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $x^3-3x^2+3x+1=(x-1)^3+2$, the second curve is a translation of the first one.

Comment: OP has $3x\color{red}+1$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I've edited my answer. Thank you.